# Disable syntax checking for one file in CLion

Tags: clion

CLion *really* doesn't like [Rapidcheck GTests](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck/blob/master/doc/gtest.md). In fact it thinks their syntax is wrong, and the auto-formatter goes haywire.

Is there any way to

1. Disable syntax checking (***not*** inspections) on a per-file basis?
2. Make the auto-formatter 'dumber' on a per-file basis, so that it basically just counts brackets?